# How can I turn off caching CSS, in Adobe CQ 5

Tags: caching, content-management-system, aem

Adobe CQ is caching my css for a component I am building. I created a clientlibs folder to add the CSS to the component. Next, I'm using the

```
<cq:includeClientLib categories="includes" />
```

tag to include the CSS in my jsp.

How can I disable caching, the CSS in CQ. (I've already cleared the browser cache, it is not a browser cache issue).

Comment: Is this on your publish server, or your internal development/author instance?

Answer (score 3):

These are just 2 common ways I clear server cache. Hope it helps someone.

### Dispatcher Flush

---

Navigate to http://yourdomain.com:4502/etc/replication/agents.author/flush.html  and click on `Test Connection`.

### Invalidating Dispatcher Cache ([source](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/dispatcher/page_invalidate.html#Manually))

---

1. Open the AEM Tools console. (http://yourdomain.com:4502/miscadmin#/etc)
2. Open the required replication agent below Tools/replication/Agents
   on author. You can use  the Dispatcher Flush agent that is installed
   by default.
3. Click Edit, and in the Settings tab ensure that Enabled
   is selected.
4. On the Transport tab, enter the URI needed to access
   Dispatcher. If you are using the standard Dispatcher Flush agent you
   will probably need to update the hostname and port; for example,
   http://:/dispatcher/invalidate.cache

   Click OK to activate the agent.

Answer (score 1):

To disable clientlib mechanism, navigate to felix console
yourhost:port/system/console/configMgr

Search for "**HTML Library Manager**"
Check "Debug" and save.

Now all CSS an JS assets are served as single files.
Also, all caches are invalidated.
Request your page once and switch off "Debug" mode when you are done.

That helps with cached files most of the time. I don't recommend this for production system!

In case you compile your clientlibs through "embed" statements within other clientlibs, edit the css.txt file and append a commented-line. Also remove cached clientlibs below var/clientlibs/etc

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CQ5 with LESS (which is already included), in the Developer console you can execute this:

```
localStorage.clear()
```

this will remove your LESS cache.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how to do this on AEM 6.1

On AEM-Author you can enable the "Dispatcher Flush" agent to invalidate cache on AEM-publish instance.

The URI will be something like this:
http://txpubt01:80/dispatcher/invalidate.cache

Where "txpubt01" is Publish instance server; "80" is the port where Apache is running on "txpubt01 server".

[image: Main page to manage replication agents]

[image: Agents on Author]

[image: Dispatcher Flush]